# Modifying Available and Chosen Choices For ManyToMany Field With Horizontal Filter In Django Model Admin

Tags: python, django

Within the Model Admin, is it possible to control what's shown in a `ManyToManyField` `horizontal_filter` widget, in both the available and chosen fields?

For instance, I have a `County` model and a `Territory` model, and want to hide a `County` if it's already assigned to a `Territory`.

The problem with the below is that selected `County` objects will be hidden in both the "Available" and "Chosen" widget with `horizontal_filter`. Is it possible to only hide them in the "Available" column?

```
class TerritoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('counties',)
    ordering = ('territory_name', )

    # remove counties already assigned to a territory
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'counties':
            assigned = Territory.objects.all(
                ).values_list('counties__fips_code', flat=True)
            kwargs["queryset"] = County.objects.exclude(fips_code__in=assigned)

        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: *"... and want to hide a `County` ..."*, hide from where? Could you add your relevant models and admin snippet that can be used to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to perform this logic in a custom `ModelForm` since you need the `instance` to include counties that have already been selected if you are editing

```
class TerritoryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, instance=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, instance=instance, **kwargs)
        counties_filter = Q(territories__isnull=True)
        if instance:
            counties_filter |= Q(territories__id=instance.id)
        self.fields['counties'].queryset = County.objects.filter(countries_filter)


@admin.register(Foo)
class TerritoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TerritoryAdminForm
    filter_horizontal = ['counties']
```

Without knowing the name of the relation between County and Territory I've assumed it's named "territories"